# Perform complex queries into combined databases from different locations

Tags: mysql, sql-server, redis

I have a complex task in here..

A client has 7 servers, all in different locations.
Each one has a database with a table of user logs.
All the server tables are the same! Only the records in them are different.
However, each user may have log records on several servers.
All 7 databases have about 10 million records.

I need to run queries using SUM, COUNT, BETWEEN DATES etc..
What will be the correct approach?
I know about federated tables, and probably this will do the job, but the performance will be an issue..

I am thinking of storing all database records in Redis and running queries there, which I never did before.

Comment: Sharing: I have similar task before and final solution was to distribute the query and perform the SQL locally on each server and aggregate the totals in the web portal server that display the results. I also use redis as a queue to line up the queries, and perform the heavy duty SQL one by one with an always running python script and POST the results back to the portal upon completion. I have 90M active records on each server and its running for two years without problem.

Comment: Thanks but not an option for me.. I need all the records together before executing the queries.

Comment: Anyone ?! Please masters.. I really need to do this right :)

Comment: for a matter of simplicity, I will use 1 redis in order to concentrate records, but if you need something more sofisticated I should use an index such as solr/lucene/elastic search.

Comment: How long do you think you need to fetch all records from MySQL and SET into redis? And the question mentions a need to query information using SUM, COUNT, and BETWEEN DATES. Actually can somebody demonstrate how can I do a "query" to SUM the value of one part of the record by filtering a date value BETWEEN DATES in redis? LUA and linear scan?